# I'm not able to save to the isolated storage?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, isolatedstorage

I'm trying to save my model in isolated storage:

```
var settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;

CurrentPlaceNowModel model = new CurrentPlaceNowModel();

settings.TryGetValue<CurrentPlaceNowModel>("model", out model);

if (model == null)
{
    MessageBox.Show("NULL");
    settings.Add("model", new CurrentPlaceNowModel());
    settings.Save();
}
else
    MessageBox.Show("NOT NULL");
```

When I start the emu i ofcourse the "NULL", but why do I keep getting it if I close the app on the emu and start it again from the menu (NOT starting it again in Visual Studio).

Should I not get "NOT NULL" 2nd time around?

Comment: And what exactly is `settings`? I could try to guess, but I'd rather not have to...

Comment: settings is var settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings; ive updated the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd do this differently and make a specific check to see if the key exists.

```
CurrentPlaceNowModel model; 

using (var settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings)
{
    if (settings.Contains("MODEL"))
    {
        model = settings["MODEL"] as CurrentPlaceNowModel;
    }
    else
    {
        model = new CurrentPlaceNowModel();
        settings.Add("MODEL", model);    
        settings.Save();
    }
}
```

This pattern of working with IsolatedStorage definitely works.

The only reason that this wouldn't work would be if `CurrentPlaceNowModel` could not be serialized with the DataContractSerializer. This is what the ApplicationSettings uses internally to serialize objects.
You can test this by serialising it this way yourself to see what happens.

Comment: Do I need to do something with CurrentPlaceNowModel to make it serializable? Maybe thats whats wrong. its only defined as public class CurrentPlaceNowModel : INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: Depending on what it does, contains and supports it may not be serilaizable. Can you show the code?

Answer (score 1):

I've just noticed what you've done wrong:

```
if (model == null)
{
    MessageBox.Show("NULL");
    settings.Add("model", model);
}
```

That's going to be equivalent to calling `settings.Add("model", null)` - so how would you expect to get a non-null value out later? I suspect you want:

```
CurrentPlaceNowModel model;

if (!settings.TryGetValue<CurrentPlaceNowModel>("model", out model))
{
    model = new CurrentPlaceNowModel();
    settings.Add("model", model);
}
```

Comment: @Jason94: And did you call `Save()` on it at any point? (It should be okay within the same run if not, but it won't have persisted...)

Comment: @Jason94: Why have you changed the code I gave to call `CurrentPlaceNowModel` *before* calling `TryGetValue`? It's pointless. It won't be doing any harm, but it's pointless. What happens if you look at the settings in the debugger when you rerun the app?

Comment: okey, shouldnt http://pastebin.com/mLANBMNm be a win win? still returns NULL 2nd time when I start the app on the emu :(

Comment: @Jason94: Yes, that should be fine - so as I said, what can you see in the settings in the debugger? (I've just noticed that the save should also be automatic, if the page is closed.)

Comment: I've put in a breakpoint at var foo = key in the following: http://pastebin.com/LCPxSQYi and it stops on that when I debug to the phone telling key is "model". But it fails the if-test... Does that help you helping me? :D Thanks for your time :D

Comment: @Jason94: That's really strange... What does the *value* show in the debugger? I wonder whether it's unable to serialize/deserialize properly.

Comment: If I change it to foreach (var key in settings.Values), it hits one time, key is a CurrentPlaceNowModel, but everything is null/defaults...

Comment: @Jason94: Just iterate over settings itself, then you should see the key and value together... Note that in the "NOT NULL" branch in your code, you *don't* need to fetch the model again - you've just grabbed it with TryGetValue!